# Torque output of transmission when accounting for moment of inertia

Tags: transmission

A cable drum is driven by 3 electric motors via a bull gear arrangement. Gear ratio, total motor inertia (including pinion gears) and total drum inertia are known. From the motor variable speed drives, the motor angular acceleration and torque are measured.

Can the following formulae be used to calculate how much torque the drum will produce? (And in turn calculate the cable tension)

$$\tau_{out} = {R\tau_{in}-\alpha(I_{motor}+{I_{drum}\over R^2}) }$$

$\tau_{out}:$ Torque out from drum, $R:$ Gear ratio, $\tau_{in}$ Torque supplied by motors, $\alpha:$ Motor angular acceleration, $I_{motor}:$ Inertia of motors and pinion gears, $I_{drum}:$ Inertia of drum and bull gear.

Note that the formulae does not account for transmission efficiency. Where in the formulae would this fit in?

Comment: Apply efficiency to the final value.

Comment: are we trying to solve for a certain set of input parameters?  Are the motors in a state of acceleration?  If so I think we are looking for the acceleration placed on the load and thus the force required to accelerate the load at the same rate.  So calculate total system acceleration, then the resulting force generated by the wire rope.  Force at a diameter = torque.

Comment: @ScottDunnington. Yes, we're solving for the parameters on the right side of the equation. Yes, the motors will have continuously varying angular acceleration. The load is not accelerated; The platform that the mechanical assembly sits on, is. Only the torque output and in turn the cable tension is of interest.